# Test program just wont invoke service, yet everything looks okay - getting 404 not found

Tags: wcf

I've created a WCF service to receive data from a sending application. When run, the usual index listing appears:

[image]

and clicking on the .svc shows the success page:

[image]

So, I've created a basic test form to invoke the methods of the service (there are 2, both are "POST" methods). Since the service methods use JSON & webhttp, I am attempting to invoke the service via an HttpWebRequest.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try { 
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54945/Take2ToOffice.svc/ErrorReport");

    request.ContentType = "'text/json; charset=utf-8'";
    request.Method = "POST";

    byte[] chunk = new byte[2048]; //chunk gets initialised, but what it 
                                   //contains is mostly irrelevant here
    string result = "";

    ErrorInfo EI = new ErrorInfo {
      Edumis = "9999",
      SiteName = "Unknown",
      ErrorID = "123",
      ContentBlock = chunk
    };

    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(EI);

    //MessageBox.Show(json);

    using (var sW = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
      sW.Write(json);
      sW.Flush();
      sW.Close();
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
      result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(result);
  }
  catch (WebException wex) {
    string lcResult;
    if (wex.Response != null) {
      lcResult = "ERROR (web exception, response generated): " + Environment.NewLine;
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream());
      lcResult += sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    else {
      lcResult = "ERROR (web exception, NO RESPONSE): " + wex.Message + wex.StackTrace;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(lcResult);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

It all seems like pretty basic stuff - especially since I wrote another service very similar to this a few years ago, and my starting point for everything I've done now, was the code I wrote previously - and at this point, I'm just doing this in my development environment.

Yet,

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Returns 404 Not Found. The WebException.Response contains:

```
{System.Net.HttpWebResponse}
    [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]: {System.Net.HttpWebResponse}
    base: {System.Net.HttpWebResponse}
    ContentLength: 0
    ContentType: ""
    Headers: {X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVXNlclxEb2N1bWVudHNcVmlzdWFsIFN0dWRpb1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTNcUHJvamVjdHNcVGFrZTJPZmZpY2VDb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uc1xUYWtlMk9mZmljZUNvbW11bmljYXRpb25zXFRha2UyVG9PZmZpY2Uuc3ZjXEVycm9yUmVwb3J0?=
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 03:19:29 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
    IsFromCache: false
    IsMutuallyAuthenticated: false
    ResponseUri: {http://localhost:54945/Take2ToOffice.svc/ErrorReport}
    SupportsHeaders: true
```

But there is no actual response at all (length = 0). If I put a breakpoint in the service, (and start both the test form, and the service - separate projects in the same solution), the breakpoint is never hit.

Logically it looks like the service isn't running, or for some reason can't be found - but the listing and success page are readily seen in a browser, and at the address (localhost:54945) shown in the program.

Can anyone explain what's going on, or maybe what's going wrong? Please help, I'm totally stumped.

The web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Take2OfficeCommunications.Take2ToOffice" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="rest" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="web" 
                  name="restEndpoint" 
                  contract="Take2OfficeCommunications.ITake2ToOffice"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport" />
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for looking, and for any comments you can make.

Comment: You have the endpoint address set as "rest" - that means your endpoint address should be something like `http://localhost:54945/rest/Take2ToOffice.svc/ErrorReport`.   `http://localhost:54945/Take2ToOffice.svc` is by default going to be your `basicHttpBinding` endpoint, and being SOAP won't understand the `/ErrorReport` portion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tim, I've removed the address from the endpoint. Sadly I have to report that doing so has not made any difference.